# Generic method vs Abstract type to the method

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I am wondering if the two methods below are essentially the same thing ?

```
public static Parent withParent(Parent p) {
    p.doSomething();
    return p;
}

public static <E entends Parent> E withGenericType(E e) {
    e.doSomething();
    return E;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
         System.out.println("override");
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
     // are they the same ?
     withParent(new Child());
     withGenericType(new Child());
}
```

and also in what case would you use one and other ?

Comment: As long as doSomething() is not overridden in the sub class then they should do the same thing...

Comment: What is the return type of generic `with` if you provide an argument of type `Child`?

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same thing.

Imagine you have a class `Child extends Parent`:

```
Child c = new Child();
c = with(c);
```

This would compile using the generic version, but not with the non-generic version (since it'd return a `Parent`, not a `Child`).

With the non-generic version, you'd have to cast the reference back to a `Child`, relying on the method's behavior to be sure that this would work:

```
Child c = new Child();
c = (Child) with(c);
```

The generics essentially add that cast for you.

Why would you want this? Consider inlining the above a bit:

```
Child c = with(new Child());
```

Comment: but what about Parent p = with(new Child()); if I don't really care about the actual type that it returns ?

Comment: @Nizil A Child is-a Parent, but that doesn't mean that `Parent p = new Child(); Child c = p;` will compile.

Comment: @user1389813 If you don't care about the the type, then yeah, you don't need the generics.